# I'm getting "This should be a Suggested Edit" when attempting to Suggest an Edit

Tags: support, bug, editing

I'm getting this error when I attempt to edit a new member's question for readability and clarity.

When I choose '*Save Edit*' it says the message "This should be a Suggested Edit".

Can someone clarify for me please?

Comment: What question are you trying to edit and how?

Comment: It had just been asked and has since been edited but [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126907/how-do-i-fix-this-run-bat-thing-for-minecraft-bukkit-servers) My edits apparently were rejected as answers which shouldn't have been the case. EDIT - I believe it was because I was a lower rep user at the time of posting.